# onchange event does not work when the element is changed by another one

Tags: jquery, onclick, onchange

I have a checkbox with onChange event and a button who check and uncheck this checkbox.
The event is fired when I check and uncheck manually. But when I press on the button to change the status of the checkbox no event is fired.

You can see the exemple here : http://jsfiddle.net/7Nws8/7/

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1">
<input type="button" id="2" value="click">
```

Do you have ideas to fire the event onchange when the button is pressed.

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$("#1").trigger("change")` to trigger change event and to toggle click `prop("checked", !$("#1").prop("checked")` .Try this:

```
 $(document).on("click","#2",function()
 {
   $("#1").trigger("change").prop("checked", !$("#1").prop("checked"));
 });
 $(document).on("change","#1",function()
 {
  alert("changed")
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Nws8/14/)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger the `change` event after setting the `checked` state of your checkbox:

```
$(document).on("click","#2",function()
{
    if($("#1").is(":checked") == true)
    {
         $("#1").prop('checked', false).change(); // or .trigger('change')
    }
    else
    {
        $("#1").prop('checked', true).change(); // or .trigger('change')
    }
})
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Nws8/8/)**

Also note that `id` start with number is not valid HTML. You can refer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)** for more informations

Answer (score 0):

Just add `trigger`

```
$(document).on("click","#2",function(){

    if($("#1").is(":checked") == true) { 
       $("#1").prop('checked', false); 
    } else {
       $("#1").prop('checked', true);
    }
    $('#1').trigger('change');
});
```

See this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Nws8/11/)

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass the click like:

```
$(document).on("click","#2",function()
{
    $('#1').click();
});
$(document).on("change","#1",function()
{
    alert("changed");
});
```

[**The demo**.](http://jsfiddle.net/7Nws8/13/)

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the event after changing the property value:

```
$(document).on("click", "#2", function () {
    var checkboxEl = $('#1');
    checkboxEl.prop('checked', !checkboxEl.is(":checked")).change()
});

$(document).on("change", "#1", function () {
    alert("changed");
});
```

It's also good to cache the jQuery object.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of do

```
 $("#1").prop('checked', false);
```

you can just do:

```
 $("#1").click();
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hWhg3/

Comment: I can't see why this answer is not useful, this works! Have you saw jsfiddle?

Comment: Triggering clicks is not a good practise. By doing it you emulate user 's behaviour and you should not be doing that. Also it's really a pain in the ass when you have to debug.